# Geany is crashing with segfault during startup

Tags: 14.04, command-line, editor, geany

Suddenly from today my Geany editor doesn't run at all neither from shortcut nor from terminal.

My Ubuntu version is 14.04 Trusty Tahr.

Geany version is 1.26.

I also tried re-installing the latest version 1.27 but still not working.

If I try to start `geany` from command-line then it gives error:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

What possibly could be the issue ? Previously it was working fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug and some kind off topic here. However, there are 2 things to do:

1: Run Geany with gdb and send a backtrace to Geany devs. [Do it like this](http://geany.org/manual/hacking.html#gdb)

- Install gdb from repository
- Run gdb Geany followed by pressing `r` for
  running
- When Geany is crashing, type `bt`  and send the out to
  Geany devs (e.g. via [GitHub](https://github.com/geany/geany/issues)) or report a bug against Ubuntu
  (Really, it's a bug for sure)

2: Most likely one of the plugins is buggy or another setting you have done is faulty. Move `~/.config/geany/geany.conf` out of the way -- e.g. renaming is ok -- and start Geany. It should start with defaults. Don't delete old geany.conf as it might be should included to the bug report from step 1 later.